# Where is the data in docker container stored in docker?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-machine

Similar question:  [mac image path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54148999/where-are-docker-images-stored-physically-on-macos)

In mac, when I run `docker inspect containerID`

I see most of the stuff is coming from /var/lib/docker/

however, this path neither exists in the host (mac) nor the docker container.

where is this path refer to?

Comment: Docker (for the most part) only runs under Linux. On a Mac (or Windows), Docker is running in a Linux virtual machine. The path `/var/lib/docker/` exists inside that virtual machine.

Comment: Even on native Linux, you shouldn't usually be directly looking at things in `/var/lib/docker`.  The image and container contents in particular are in a complex installation-specific format, and you can't directly read or write it from the host.

Answer (score 0):

you can find your files in `container:path` and use the docker commands to copy them to your local machine and vice versa (I'm assuming you are trying to move files e.g. from your local machine to your container). I had the same exact issue you mentioned but I manage to move files with

```
docker cp local_path containerID:target_path
```

to see your `container_ID` simply run `docker ps -a`, it should show it even if unmounted.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/